# how to remove duplicate words in a certain pattern from a string in R

Tags: r

I aim to remove duplicate words only in parentheses from string sets.

```
a = c( 'I (have|has|have) certain (words|word|worded|word) certain',
'(You|You|Youre) (can|cans|can) do this (works|works|worked)',
'I (am|are|am) (sure|sure|surely) you know (what|when|what) (you|her|you) should (do|do)' )
```

What I want to get is just like this

```
a
[1]'I (have|has) certain (words|word|worded) certain'
[2]'(You|Youre) (can|cans) do this (works|worked)'
[3]'I (am|are) pretty (sure|surely) you know (what|when) (you|her) should (do|)'
```

In order to get the result, I used a code like this

```
a = gsub('\\|', " | ",  a)
a = gsub('\\(', "(  ",  a)
a = gsub('\\)', "  )",  a)
a = vapply(strsplit(a, " "), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = " "), character(1L))
```

However, it resulted in undesirable outputs.

```
a    
[1] "I (  have | has ) certain words word worded"                 
[2] "(  You | Youre ) can cans do this works worked"              
[3] "I (  am | are ) sure surely you know what when her should do"
```

Why did my code remove parentheses located in the latter part of strings?
What should I do for the result I want?

Comment: I'm worried about the unique(x) getting rid of the duplicate parantheses

Comment: Try `sub` instead of `gsub`. The `gsub` function means "global" substitution. The `sub` function affects only the first occurrence of the regexp match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn`.  Here, the idea is to select the characters inside the brackets by matching the opening bracket (`\\(` have to escape the bracket as it is a metacharacter) followed by one or more characters that are not a closing bracket (`[^)]+`), capture it as a group within the brackets.  In the replacement, we split the group of characters (`x`) with `strsplit`, `unlist` the `list` output, get the `unique` elements and `paste` it together

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\(([^)]+)", ~paste0("(", paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, 
                "[|]"))), collapse="|")), a)
#[1] "I (have|has) certain (words|word|worded) certain"                   
#[2] "(You|Youre) (can|cans) do this (works|worked)"                      
#[3] "I (am|are) (sure|surely) you know (what|when) (you|her) should (do)"
```

Comment: Thank YOU SO MUCH. I thougt it would not be possible.

Comment: I would really like an explanation of how this works.

Comment: @Haboryme  I added some explanation

Comment: that is cool.. the answer that I created was about 10 lines long! This is magic of pro :)

Comment: @Mandar Thanks for the comments.  You will also become good in coding with consistent practice.

Comment: I agree. Sir. I think you should be able to see my response (that I have already deleted). Can you see deleted answers?

Comment: @Mandar Yes, I can see your deleted answer.  You had two `for` loops, and `ifelse` whiile `ifelse` is vectorized

Comment: It still shows weird staring and ending point. Can you see why did it not work (it shows some NA strings)

Comment: @Mandar Another case is `strsplit` which can work on `vectors`.  So, it is not clear why you need to apply `strsplit` on each elemnt on vector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134398/discussion-between-mandar-and-akrun).

Comment: @Mandar If you are using `strsplit` one option is `sapply(strsplit(a, "(?<=\\()|(?=\\))", perl = TRUE), function(x) {i1 <- grep("[|]", x); x[i1] <- sapply(strsplit(x[i1], "[|]"), function(y) paste(unique(y), collapse="|"));paste(x, collapse="")})`

Comment: I will use it next time. Btw I just edited my code. and its working :))

Answer (score 2):

Take the answer above. This is more straightforward, but you can also try:

```
library(stringi)
library(stringr)
a_new <- gsub("[|]","-",a) # replace this | due to some issus during the replacement later
a1 <- str_extract_all(a_new,"[(](.*?)[)]") # extract the "units"
# some magic using stringi::stri_extract_all_words()
a2 <- unlist(lapply(a1,function(x) unlist(lapply(stri_extract_all_words(x), function(y) paste(unique(y),collapse = "|")))))
# prepare replacement
names(a2) <- unlist(a1)
# replacement and finalization
str_replace_all(a_new, a2)
[1] "I (have|has) certain (words|word|worded) certain"                   
[2] "(You|Youre) (can|cans) do this (works|worked)"                      
[3] "I (am|are) (sure|surely) you know (what|when) (you|her) should (do)"
```

The idea is to extract the words within the brackets as unit. Then remove the duplicates and replace the old unit with the updated.

Answer (score 1):

a longer but more elaborate try

```
a = c( 'I (have|has|have) certain (words|word|worded|word) certain',
       '(You|You|Youre) (can|cans|can) do this (works|works|worked)',
       'I (am|are|am) (sure|sure|surely) you know (what|when|what) (you|her|you) should (do|do)' )
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

# blank output     
new_a <- c()
for (sentence in 1:length(a)) {
split <- trim(unlist(strsplit(a[sentence],"[( )]")))
newsentence <- c()
for (i in split) {
  j1 <- as.character(unique(trim(unlist(strsplit(gsub('\\|'," ",i)," ")))))
   if( length(j1)==0) {
     next
   } else {
     ifelse(length(j1)>1,
         newsentence <- c(newsentence,paste("(",paste(j1,collapse="|"),")",sep="")),
         newsentence <- c(newsentence,j1[1]))
   }
}
newsentence <- paste(newsentence,collapse=" ")
print(newsentence)
new_a <- c(new_a,newsentence)}
# [1] "I (have|has) certain (words|word|worded) certain"                 
# [2] "(You|Youre) (can|cans) do this (works|worked)"                    
# [3] "I (am|are) (sure|surely) you know (what|when) (you|her) should do"
```